# unable to try catch sonarapi in python

Tags: python-3.x, try-catch

Team,
I have the api working fine but at times I see 404 due to calling it quickly. so I want to set in retry until I get 200 because the data sometimes takes long time to show up on server hence api throws 404 when request is made before data is available.
For that I thought would incorporate try/catch mechanism but I cant get it to work say 5 retries. any hint what am i missing?

[sonar api ref](https://python-sonarqube-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/qualitygates.html?highlight=status)

```
sonar_api()
    sonar = SonarQubeClient(sonarqube_url=sq_api_url, username=sonar_usr, password=sonar_pd)
    gerrit_cn_ps="1396449-10"

    max_retries=5
    for _ in range(max_retries):
        try:
            print(_)        
            project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey=projectKey, pullRequest=gerrit_cn_ps)
             break
        except TimeoutError:
            pass
    ps_conditions = project_pull_requests['projectStatus']['conditions']
print(sonar_api())
```

output shows 404 in last line and exits. I want to do the call again until i see 200. how can i?

```
Command> python3 sonar-api.py 
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sonar-api.py", line 84, in <module>
    print(sonar_api())
  File "sonar-api.py", line 58, in sonar_api
    project_pull_requests = sonar.qualitygates.get_project_qualitygates_status(projectKey=projectKey, pullRequest=gerrit_cn_ps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sonarqube/utils/common.py", line 132, in inner_func
    response = self._get(url_pattern, params=params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sonarqube/utils/rest_client.py", line 141, in _get
    return self.request("GET", path=path, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sonarqube/utils/rest_client.py", line 99, in request
    raise NotFoundError(msg)
sonarqube.utils.exceptions.NotFoundError: Error in request. Possibly Not Found error [404]: Pull request '1396449-10' in project 'PullBranchAnalysis' not found
```